# Can I represent a red black tree as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, red-black-tree

Is it worth representing a red black tree as an array to eliminate the memory overhead. Or will the array take up more memory since the array will have empty slots?

Comment: How would you represent the RBT in an array, first of all? Edit your question to add this detail!

Comment: I'll be coding in c. With the -O3 turned on.

Comment: My question was: how would you use the array? How would you represent red and black nodes in an array, and how would you maintain the 5 properties, etc? Answer to these questions. Then we can give you an answer.

Comment: There is no more overhead in a red-black tree than in any other data structure. The rotations on additions to the tree are minimal compared to the benefit of data retrieval for large data sets. If you use an array (of structs) to replace the tree, you lose all relational sorting the tree provides on traversal. You can store data in whatever data structure you choose, the decision is based on how you will use the data and the performance requirements you have.

Comment: I guess @jsho was going to use an array as it is used for binary heap: root value has index 1 in the array, for value that has index `N` left child has index `N*2`, right child has index `N*2 + 1`, parent has index `N div 2`. For red-black tree you will need two arrays one for values and one for colour. You can save some memory if you use a bit set for the colours.

Comment: Do you really need two arrays? You can combine color, key and value into a node. The node just doesn't require pointers like a linked-list style tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have both positive and negative sides. This answer is applicable for C [since you mentioned this is what you will use]

**Positive sides**

1. Lets assume you have created an array as pool of objects that you will use for red-black tree. Deleting an element or initializing a new element when the position is found will be a little fast, because you probably will use the memory pool you have created yourself.

**Negative sides**

1. Yes the array will most probably end up taking more memory since the array will have empty slots sometimes.
2. You have to be sure about the MAX size of the red-black trees in this case. So there is a limitation of size.
3. You are not using the benefit of sequential memory space, so that might be a waste of resource.

Comment: If you are implementing a data page with sorted data elements, then the array size is fixed anyway, right? Like a b-tree node, for example. So the negatives in this case might be offset. Pointers to left and right nodes are offset calculations instead of pointers, so  you trade memory cost for compute cost.

Answer (score 1):

Red-back tree (and most data structures, really) doesn't care about which storage facility is used, that means you can use array or even HashTable/Map to store the tree node, the array index or map key is your new "pointer". You can even put the tree on the disk as a file and use file offset as node index if you would like to (though, in this case, you should use B-Tree instead).

The main problem is increased complexity as now you have to manage the storage manually (opposed to letting the OS and/or language runtime do it for you). Sometimes you want to scale the array up so you can store more items, sometimes you want to scale it down (vacuum) to free up unused space. These operations can be costly on their own.

Memory usage wise, storage facility does not change how many nodes on the tree. If you have 2,000 nodes on your old school pointer*er* tree (tree height=10), you'll still have 2,000 nodes on your fancy array*ilized* tree (tree height is still 10). However, redundant space may exists in between vacuum operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can represent red-black tree as an array, but it's not worth it.

Maximum height of red-black tree is 2*log2(n+1), where n is number of entries. Number of entries in array representation on each level is 2**n, where n is level. So to store 1_000 entries you'd have to allocate array of 1_048_576 entries. To store 1_000_000 entries you'd have to allocate array of 1_099_511_627_776 entries.

It's not worth it.

Comment: To store 1_000 levels you would need  1_048_576 entries, no?

Comment: Why? If I want to store 1k entries, I just need a 1k slot array. Index 0 is root and level 0, indexes 1 and 2 are level 1, indexes 3, 4, 5, and six are level 2, and so on. Maybe I am missing something? Oh, 1k levels, not 1k entries? But who cares how many levels? I just need to allocate an array large enough to hold a page of data, no?